# What is a better option to many if statements with different combinations of filters?

Tags: javascript

```
if(weekly_trending === "true" &&  monthly_trending === "true" 
   && quarterly_trending === "true" 
   && sort_by_likes === "true" 
   && sort_by_date === "true" ){
      return  
}
```

These are the filters I want to use in my API, but I want to allow to use only one of these filter at a time, like only `weekly_trending === "true"`, not any other from the list.

I can do that using `if` statements like this, but I have to write so much code. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: If you put the selected filters into an array, you could use [`.every(filter => filter === "true")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: Try to write your title in a way that helps distinguish your question from other similar questions on this site.

Comment: Usually you do this by using any of many existing API solutions (which already come with this kind of filtering) rather than rolling your own, giving you your time back to work on the parts that are specific to your use-case, rather than spending time and effort on implementing functionality that others already wrote and is freely available as open source libraries.

Comment: Is the goal here to write something equivalent to your example code but using more economical syntax?  Or is the goal really to **"allow to use only one of these filter at a time"**?  Because I think a lot of people here will answer with equivalent code, and your intent of trying to allow only one of those will get lost as noise.

Answer (score 1):

something you can do is create an array from all your boolean and with `array.filter` get an array of all one equal to true

```
var conditions = [
  weekly_trending,
  monthly_trending,
  quarterly_trending,
  sort_by_likes,
  sort_by_date
];
conditions.filter(condition => condition)
```

array.filter is a method that :

- iterate on array element
- should return true or false for all of them take in callback pass in parameter
- in the end it return another array where element that match condition equal true are present

your `if` can be simplified to

```
if(conditions.filter(condition => condition).length === 1){
```

```js
var weekly_trending = true;
var monthly_trending = false;
var quarterly_trending = false;
var sort_by_likes = false;
var sort_by_date = false;

function getConditions() {
  return [
    weekly_trending,
    monthly_trending,
    quarterly_trending,
    sort_by_likes,
    sort_by_date
  ];
}

function validate() {
  var conditions = getConditions();
  if(conditions.filter(condition => condition).length === 1) { 
    console.log('win');
  } else {
    console.log('failed');
  }
}


validate();
monthly_trending = true;
validate();
```

Comment: You should explain your code, and add documentation to methods probably unfamiliar to the OP [like `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Code dumps are very helpful.

Comment: i add an explaination of logical in my reply and how array.filter run

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution will do if you want to limit only one filter for your API:

```js
const filterWeeklyTrending = (unfilteredResults) => {/*...*/}
// rest of the possible filter functions...

const filterFunctions = {
  weekly_trending: filterWeeklyTrending,
  monthly_trending: filterMonthlyTrending,
  // rest of the possible filters...
}

// Suppose you are using Express and queries live in `req.param` like so:
// { weekly_trending: 1 }
// We want to return an array of matched filter names here.
const matchedFilterNames = Object.keys(filterFunctions).filter(key => key in req.param) // e.g. ['weekly_trending']

if (matchedFilterNames.length !== 1) {
  // tell client they must provide only 1 filter
  return
}

// otherwise, filter results
const selectedFilterFunction = filterFunctions[matchedFilterNames[0]]
const filteredResults = selectedFilterFunction(unfilteredResults)
```

However, if you are building an API, and the filter is specified by the end user, would a slightly different design that forces the end user to only be able to choose one filter from the start mitigate the problem?

e.g. if it's an HTTP API, it would indicate better to the user to only provide one filter option if instead of `http://my.site/api/sports?weekly_trending=true`, we have `http://my.site/api/sports?sort=weekly_trending`?

Then we can substitute the following:

```js
const matchedFilterNames = Object.keys(filterFunctions).filter(key => key in req.param) // e.g. ['weekly_trending']

if (matchedFilterNames.length !== 1) {
  // tell client they must provide only 1 filter
  return
}
```

with

```js
const filterName = req.params.sort // if this is where user specifies the filter function

if (!(filterName in filterFunctions)) {
  // tell client this filter does not exist
  return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper Class Validator to add your rules as you need and validate the result.

```js
const weekly_trending = true;
const monthly_trending = true;
const quarterly_trending = true;
const sort_by_likes = true;
const sort_by_date = true;

class Validator {
    constructor() {
        this.rules = [];
    }

    addRules(...rules) {
        this.rules.push(...rules);
    }

    validate() {
        if (this.rules.every(rule => rule === true)) {
            console.log("all true");
        }
    }
}

const validator = new Validator();

validator.addRules(
    weekly_trending,
    monthly_trending,
    quarterly_trending,
    sort_by_likes,
    sort_by_date
);

validator.validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your rules to an array, and create a function that takes the array of rules and checks if they're all true

```js
const rules = [weekly_trending, monthly_trending, quarterly_trending, sort_by_likes, sort_by_date]

if (validator(rules)) {
    // do something
}

function validator(rules){
    if (rules.every(rule => rule === "true")){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

---

or you can just do this if you prefer to write less code

```js
const rules = [weekly_trending, monthly_trending, quarterly_trending, sort_by_likes, sort_by_date]

if (rules.every(rule => rule === "true")) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example the function `flagFilter()` takes two @param:

- first @param is an array of flags (Booleans)
- second @param is a flag that if ignored defaults to `false`. If `true` is passed, then the array will run with `.some()` array method. `.some()` will see if a flag is `true`. Once it finds it's first `true` it quits and returns `true` otherwise it'll return `false`. If `false` is passed then `.every()` array method is used. `.every()` requires every flag to be `true` otherwise it will return `false`.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
// Utility function
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// Define flags (note: Booleans are not quoted
const weekly = false, monthly = false, quarterly = false, likes = true, date = false;

// Define an array of the flags
const flags = [weekly, monthly, quarterly, likes, date];

/**
 * Iterate through a given array of
 * Booleans and see if all or at least
 * one is true.
 * @param {array<boolean>} array - An
 * array of booleans
 * @param {boolean} mode - (@default false) 
 * if true then only one true flag is
 * needed otherwise all flags need to 
 * be true.
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const flagFilter = (array, mode = false) => mode == true ? array.some(f => f) : array.every(f => f);

// Needs all flags to be true
log(flagFilter(flags));
// Needs only one flag to be true
log(flagFilter(flags, true));
```